# UDP server reset

Tags: c#, udp

I have a very simple C# app that is supposed to listen on a UDP port and write any incoming data to a listbox. The whole thing is as follows:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(44557);

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipep = null;
        var rcv = udpc.EndReceive(ar, ref ipep);
        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcv);
        this.Invoke((Action)(()=>lsbLog.Items.Add(s)));
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        udpc.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), udpc);
    }
}
```

It gets the first packet and logs it, but that is it. How do I "reset" it to keep receiving?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is not a "tag", but part of the question. The UDP socket not resetting itself is not part of UDP, but rather specifically part of C#'s UDP class design.

Comment: C# has no UDP support. Perhaps you mean .NET UDP? It can't be "C# UDP" if the same thing is used for VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each receive is kicked off with a `BeginReceive` and completed via `EndReceive`.  You need to call `BeginReceive` again after the first receive is completed in order to continue receiving inbound data.

Check out "Handling received UDP packets" [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132623/Basic-UDP-Receiver) to see the pattern you need.